# Reading from change tracking tables - what transaction isolation level?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When reading from the change tracking tables what transaction isolation level do I need? Does the change tracking table update if there's an on-going transaction e.g. inserting a row in a tracked table? I am experiencing locking issues due to frequent querying and currently I am using the highest possible transaction isolation level when querying, but maybe this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean change tracking (not CDC), I would recommend you to check the official documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-snapshot-isolation

> Change tracking has been designed to work well with snapshot
> isolation. Snapshot isolation must be enabled for the database. All
> the steps that are required to obtain changes must be included inside
> a snapshot transaction. This will ensure that all changes that are
> made to data while obtaining changes will not be visible to the
> queries inside the snapshot transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Change tracking is designed to use snapshot isolation level to achieve information consistency. But note that it may cause overuse of tempdb database (row versioning).